# Switching JRE version

Tags: windows-8.1, java, android, jdk, jre

I have JDK 1.8.0_05 64 bit, 1.6.0_45 64 bit and 1.6.0_39 32 bit versions installed on a same machine. I am using this machine for Android app development and it was working fine with Native Android app development.

However I need to use this machine for a cross platform SDK which doesn't support Java 8 for development. The last supported version is Java 6. The SDK is Marmalade if anyone interested. However Whenever I try to build APK with it, it keeps on giving in `[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]` error, which I guessed is due to unsupported Java version.

I changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable to point 1.6 64 bit version along with `PATH`. However whenever I run `java -version` command, it returns

```
C:\Batch>java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

I think that's because of JRE version, not JDK. So I renamed the jre8 dir to some random name and retried which gave me following error -

```
C:\Batch>java -version
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Whatever question I found on SU and SO they mentioned Environment path solution which works for JDK, but I want the solution for JRE. Is there any way I can switch to `jre6` without uninstalling `jre8`?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that the Java 8 copied Java.exe in System32 folder which I renamed and the command prompt started giving Java 6 version after that.

Thanks for the answers to this question - [Wrong java -version being reported](https://superuser.com/questions/479889/wrong-java-version-being-reported)