# Windows 10 shows wrong Java version

Tags: windows-10, java, environment-variables, jdk

On newly installed windows 10 64bit, I did install first, Oracle JDK 12, then installed Oracle JDK 8 update 211, and finally installed Oracle JDK 11.

So now in the `C:\Program Files\Java\` there exits 4 folders

```
jdk1.8.0_211, jdk-11.0.3, jdk-12.0.1, jre1.8.0_211
```

In the `Environment Varibales -> System Varibales` I have the `JAVA_HOME` with value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3` and in the path I have added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

**But yet** after logout/login and restart still the command `java -version` on cmd and git bash **outputs wrong version**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

How should I fix the problem?

Comment: What are the full contents of your `PATH` variable? Is the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` before all other Java paths?

Comment: What problem?  `java -version` is showing the correct information (of course it isn't what you expect it to be).  Please provide the contents of your PATH variable.  I suspect if you use `java -2 -version` you will get different results.  I suspect you will find that the JRE 8 is the cause of your problems.  It is unclear the reason you have multiple versions installed.  Java 12 has the capability to run Java 11 and Java 8 applications.  You can even compile an application to a specific JDK version (depending on the IDE).

Comment: Oppps, There was a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` in the Path

Comment: @Ramhound  :)) seriously `what problem?` I have written several paragraphs to describe the problem. Having several Java versions is essential for my work. the problem is that I am not a Windows user

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi - You indicated it was giving you the wrong version, except it, wasn't, it was giving you the correct version due to the contents of your PATH variable.  I am very familiar with the need for multiple versions of Java.  I was just pointing out the fact, multiple versions of the JDK, are not technically required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/479918/749942)
the commands `for %I in (java.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:I` showed that there exists a wrong path to `java.exe` in the `Path` variable. As the contents of the Path was too long I was not seeing it. in my case (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`)

So the solution is:

- Move that to the end of the list or delete it
- rename all `java*.exe` files to e.g. `java*_foo.exe` in case of future use